# Most efficient way to add javascript file to specific post and/or pages?

Tags: php, custom-field, jquery, javascript

I am wondering what the most efficient method is to add a javascript file specifically for a post and/or page.

Here are a few solutions I came up with:

- Switch to HTML editing view and post your JavaScript in there (pretty bad solution)
- Custom fields with the specific JavaScript for that post/page in the key & value pairs
- In footer.php, load JavaScript files depending on which page you're on (this leads to a lot of conditionals though)

On a side note, none of the JavaScript files will be shared between pages - it will literally be specific to what you're currently viewing.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Meta boxes / custom fields are your best option

Comment: How would you define efficiency?

Comment: By 'efficient' I mean the least amount of code redundancy and the most effective way to go about doing this specifically for a single post/page.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I think the best balance between efficiency, and using proper wordpress methods for adding javascript would be adding something along these lines to your themes functions.php file. For Example:

**functions.php:**

```
function load_scripts() {
    global $post;

    if( is_page() || is_single() )
    {
        switch($post->post_name) // post_name is the post slug which is more consistent for matching to here
        {
            case 'home':
                wp_enqueue_script('home', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/home.js', array('jquery'), '', false);
                break;
            case 'about-page':
                wp_enqueue_script('about', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/about-page.js', array('jquery'), '', true);
                break;
            case 'some-post':
                wp_enqueue_script('somepost', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/somepost.js', array('jquery'), '1.6', true);
                break;
        }
    } 
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_scripts');
```

This gives you full control over what gets loaded where, a centralized location in your themes functions.php file for editing what gets loaded where: and, this way uses wordpress methods for adding javascript to your posts and pages ***safely***.

Comment: Nice little function. You're right about it being useful to have a 'centralized location'. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: I guess this can be cleaned up a bit. You're basically checking the same thing with two different switch-cases. I'd say combine both switch-cases, and the conditional if could be `if (is_page() || is_single())`. What do you think Ben?

Comment: Sounds like an improvement to me. Good one!

Comment: @Ben is it the *functions.php*  one inside theme or in *wp-includes* ? my page title is  *Access to Home Online* and I have put your function changeing `home` to `Access to Home Online` but it is not working ?

Comment: @Ciastopiekarz I've updated my answer to better show that the code goes in your themes functions.php file.

Comment: No problem I got it working long time back

Comment: This does not work for child themes, but this can be easily fixed. Replace get_template_directory_uri() with get_stylesheet_directory_uri()

Answer (score 4):

What I would do is either place in the footer or header and use php conditionals.

For example:

```
<?php if (is_page ('your-page')){?>

  <script type="text/javascript" src"the file path"></script>

<?php } elseif ( is_page ('another')){?>

  <script type="text/javascript" src"the file path"></script>

<?php } else { ?>

  <script type="text/javascript" src"the file path"></script>

<?php } ?>
```

This way your not calling all the scripts all the time on each page load and your only calling the ones you need.

Here is a link to the Wordpress codex http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags

And if you have special scripts that might only need to be called on a per post basis use custom fields.

Comment: Thanks Nicole - this was #3. It's a decent solution considering I'm not going to have many pages... still considering it.

Comment: Whati have above can used with the various items of the wordpress codex such as: is_categories, is_single (for posts), is_post_type ... I added a link to wordpress's conditional list in my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

The other tested way is below add in page directly from editor and do add comments  with in script tag other wise it won't work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var a = 5;
alert("hello world. The value of a is: " + a);
-->
</script>
```