# adding script tag in head of specific pages

Tags: javascript, headers, scripts, custom-header

I just added a new page which needed some javascript to pull json(with setInterval) and display content in that page div tag, On digging i discovered we can add script tag in themes/header.php file .

but that means it would load with all the pages or blog maybe, but I just want the javascript to load for that specific page.

```
function debug_to_console( $data ) {
    if ( is_array( $data ) )
        $output = "<script>console.log( 'Debug Objects: " . implode( ',', $data) . "' );</script>";
    else
        $output = "<script>console.log( 'Debug Objects: " . $data . "' );</script>";
    echo $output;
}

function loadJScriptforAho(){
        if  ( $post->ID == 75){
        debug_to_console( "Testing" );
        }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'loadJScriptforAho' );
```

Above code added to *functions.php* but doesn't work

I'd imagine that might be possible but if someone can share how to that please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple google search can help you do this, well same question was answered before, you can see the [answer here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/67802/most-efficient-way-to-add-javascript-file-to-specific-post-and-or-pages).

Use WordPress methods in your **functions.php** to do this :

```
function load_scripts() {
    global $post;
    wp_register_script( 'home', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/home.js', array('jquery'));
    wp_register_script( 'about', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/about.js', array('jquery'));
    wp_register_script( 'somepost', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/somepost.js', array('jquery'));

    if( is_page() || is_single() )
    {
        switch($post->post_name) 
        {
            case 'home':
                wp_enqueue_script('home');
                break;
            case 'about':
                wp_enqueue_script('about');
                break;
            case 'some-post':
                wp_enqueue_script('somepost');
                break;
        }
    } 
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_scripts');
```

Comment: to test, I added the code posted in updated post to *functions.php* and nothing happened ! are you sure which php file am I supposed to add the function provided in solution to the link you shared ?

Comment: are you sure about the names?

Answer (score 0):

WordPress had hooks to achieve this..
Every page had a unique ID (post `ID`) this globally available in a page.

```
global $post;
If( $post->ID = 22 ) {
// Your code
}
```

Comment: this sits in which php page ? I meant by pages though not posts I hope you meant to edit page hooks !

Comment: Use wp_head action hook.. in WordPress pages also refer posts ( posts and pages are stored in one table with different post_type ) if you need an example code please comment it.. i'll post an example code

Comment: Yea please do, I am new to wordpress CMS and learning php with it, so an example would be great with div tag  if condition is true for specific page

Answer (score 0):

You can do this a couple of ways, depending on how the page has been setup.

1) Page Template:

If you have a page template assigned to that specific page, you can use the following tags:

```
<?php if ( is_page_template('TEMPLATE FILE NAME') ) { ?>
    <!-- CONTENT GOES HERE -->
<?php } ?>
```

2) Page ID:

Like suggested above, you can do this by page ID - but I would do this slightly different:

```
<?php if ( is_page('ID OF PAGE GOES HERE') ) { ?>
    <!-- CONTENT GOES HERE -->
<?php } ?>
```

Let me know how you get on...

Comment: in which php module should I add ?